# Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 R2 can not send video call to multiple users

Tags: video, ms-office-communicator

I have installed Microsoft Communication Server 2007 R2 and Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 R2 for three users.

It is possible to do a video call from one person to another - you choose a person from your contact list and from context menu choose `send video call`.

But when I choose several people with which which I want to have a video chat (a video conference) this option is not avaliable, but it should be:

[image: http://www.useto.ru/images/01/image015.jpg]
<sub>(source: [useto.ru](http://www.useto.ru/images/01/image015.jpg))</sub>

What causes this, and how enable the functionality for having a video call to multiple people?

Comment: Not meaning to be rude but that screenshot's in russian(?) and apart from the icon of a webcam, I've no idea what it's meant to be saying :P

Answer (score 1):

I believe this requires a Enterprise license.